# Jenkins copy to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, jenkins, hdfs, marathon

I have tried several artifacts plugins for Jenkins but so far have been unsuccessful with the task:

I use hadoop as a file system for deployments and deploy my app from hadoop (mesos/marathon can only access http or hdfs). How do I make Jenkins save the artifact zip from sbt to hdfs? I doesnt give me the option to run a shellcommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin [Hudson Post build task](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task) lets you run shell commands and copies the necessary files to hadoop as a shell script

Comment: ^ link is broken. :(